# Unable to Call the Corda Put API from the Cordapp tutorial

Tags: corda

I am following the instructions given at the cordapp-tutorial.

I am making the following curl request from command line

curl -X PUT http://localhost:10013/api/example/create-iou?iouValue=12345678&partyName=CN%3DNodeB%2CO%3DNodeB%2CL%3DNew%20York%2CC%3DUS

Please note - I am using "" and not '' as given in the tutorial.

also when I go from the example web page what I get is this:
[image]

PS:
The web/example works fine
The Get commands work fine

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Specifically how should this API request be structured.
Would be great if you could provide the working curl request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Note that external links will rot fast, meaning this question will become less useful over time. But all relevant details in the body of the question.

Comment: @jdv I do not believe that users with low rep can post images directly.

Answer (score 0):

The web server is telling you that it is configured to deny the "PUT" request. This is what "Method not allowed" means. Not all methods (GET,POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS) are allow for all resources. In fact, most servers deny PUT and DELETE methods for most resources.